# Multitasking-view icon problem

Tags: multitasking-view

I'm new on this forum and I'm writing because since I upgraded to Juno (via clean installation), I'm not able to see the multitasking-view application icon. Instead of the right icon I see the default one as you can see from the image.
How can I solve it? 
Thanks to all [image]

Comment: can you please tell us what contains the file: /usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop ?

for that open it with a text editor  or run in ur terminal the command `cat /usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop`  and copy it here (dont forget to paste it between ``` paste me here  ``` )

Comment: or  <pre><code> paste me here </code></pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that who encountered this problem is italian (including me) and thinking about it I've figured out how to solve the problem!

Editing the file (with sudo):

```
/usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop
```

and replacing the row

```
Icon[it]=vista-multitasking
```

with

```
Icon[it]=multitasking-view
```

solved the problem!

---

Ho notato che tutti noi che abbiamo riscontrato questo problema siamo italiani, e da lì mi è venuta l'illuminazione:

Andando infatti a modificare il file (con sudo):

```
/usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop
```

e sostituendo la riga

```
Icon[it]=vista-multitasking
```

con

```
Icon[it]=multitasking-view
```

si risolve il problema!
Probabilmente il file relativo all'icona italiana è mancante o chissà cos'altro.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem introducing the following line directly on the terminal:

`sudo sed -i '/Icon[.*]/d' /usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop`

It removes all entries with the pattern "Icon=[.*]" from the file /usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop that cause the problem and leaves only the correct line which says: Icon=multitasking-view

The icon is part of Gala and the problem has been reported on GitHub:

http://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/358